# Running a method works in BroadcastReceiver but then a looped method fails

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

If I run my `onReceive()` method with just a simple toast, my app runs. But when I try to perform a loop and then show a toast, my program crashes. Is there something saying that I can't perform loops in an `onReceive()` method?

```
  @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            DBAdapter havetododb = new DBAdapter(ctx);
            Cursor cursor = havetododb.fetchAllItems();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item"));
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

I tried to search my logcat for errors, but it seems to come up empty.

Comment: Can u post the full method? it looks like an endless loop.

Comment: I cannot tell the reason by this code and no log, I guess it may be 1. too many data, stack overflow. 2. null pointer 3. some lines of code must run in a different thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any code, but if you run for too long on the main thread (I think it is 10 seconds, but it depends on what release) you will get an Application Not Responding (ANR) interruption, and you get killed. That should show up in the log though. Surround your code by a try/catch that catches all and see what you get.

If you run out of time an [IntentService]/http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) will help you. It could also be enough to execute in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) but that does less effort to keep your process alive.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. But I only have like 3 records in there, so I don't get why it would stall on that.

Comment: Then add logs and catch potential exceptions to see what's going on.